# delete lines not (containing pattern and 2 lines above pattern)

Tags: vim

In Vim I try to delete all lines in a file not (containing a pattern and 2 lines above the pattern). I try:

```
:g!/pattern/.-2 d
```

But it says: invalid range...
What to do?

Comment: What happens if 2 lines above a pattern there is another pattern? You question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then how should i delete all the lines exept the lines 4, 5 and 6 in the folowing file: line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4 line 5 line containing pattern line 7 ?

Like this:

```
:v/\v(.*\n){,2}.*pattern.*/d
```

This matches if:

- the line contains the pattern, or
- next line contains the pattern, or
- the 2nd next line contains the pattern.

These lines are kept. All *other* lines (`:v`) are deleted.

---

Example:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
id est laborum."
```

Run:

```
:v/\v(.*\n){,2}.*labor.*/d
```

Result:

```
consectetur adipiscing elit,                -2
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt            -1
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.          <-0 labor(e)
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud       -1
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut       <-0 labor(is)
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in    -2
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim      -1
id est laborum."                           <-0 labor(um)
```

Comment: Also work :%s/\(^.*\n\)\{1,2}.*labor.*\n\zs\|.*\n//g

Answer (score 4):

The command below looks for lines that don't match `pattern` and deletes them and the two lines above:

```
:g!/pattern/-2,.d
```

The command below looks for lines that don't match `pattern` and deletes the line located two lines above:

```
:g!/pattern/-2d
```

Ranges always go downwards so we use the upper address first — `-2` — and the lower one second — `.` —.

That said, you'll most likely get an error if a matching line doesn't have two lines above it.

Comment: I've made a habit about it to use `d_`. A huge difference in performance when applied to large files *(though it might have something to do with my clipboard=unnamed setting. Never took the time to verify that)*

Comment: Actually, no, it isn't supposed to work.  The command is parsed like this: `(:g!/pattern/) (-2,.d)`.  Now, `-2,.d` is not a valid syntax for `d`.  If you replace it by `.-2,.d` the syntax is valid, but then `!/pattern/` probably also matches the first line in the file, and that makes `.-2` invalid.  Something like `3,$g!/pattern/ .-2,.d` doesn't work either, because then `g` is applied line by line.  Negations are tricky. :)

Comment: `.-2,.`, `.-2,`, `-2,.` and `-2,` are all synonymous and perfectly valid ranges for any line-oriented Ex command, including `d`. The problem, here, is most likely that the first line where `:g!/pattern/` matches is the first line in the file: since there is no line above a range starting before the current line is invalid.

Comment: then how should i delete all the lines exept the lines 4, 5 and 6 in the folowing file:
`line 1  
line 2  
line 3  
line 4  
line 5  
line containing pattern  
line 7`  
(not easy to format this with linebreaks :-(  )

Comment: A-hah, so what you want is "keep each line with pattern, together with the line above and also the line above that one". Not to delete a line without pattern, together with both lines above one such line (without a pattern).